# Disable webpack function mangling on specific files

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

I'm using webpack to bundle my angular app.

One of the bundled files includes all the models required by the app, the models are defined using constructor functions.

Webpack, through it's UglifyJS plugin, mangles my constructor function names which results in different complications.

I want to prevent webpack from mangling function names only on this specific asset.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of webpack are you targeting?

Comment: v4, latest stable one

Comment: Does it work out for you? Ping me, if u have trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more detailed configuration options [see](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#options)

You can try to add multiple instances of the `UglifyJSPlugin`.
One which spits out function names and
one that generates mangled ones.

Use `exclude/include/test` to narrow down your target files for each instance!

```
optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                test: ...
                include: ...
                exclude: ...
                uglifyOptions: {
                    ecma: 5,
                    warnings: true,
                    mangle: false,
                    keep_fnames: true, <-----  keep it
                    output: {
                        beautify: true,
                        comments: true
                    }
                }
            }),
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                test: ...
                include: ...
                exclude: ...
                uglifyOptions: {
                    ecma: 5,
                    warnings: true,
                    mangle: true,
                    keep_fnames: false,  <-- mangle them
                    output: {
                        beautify: false,
                        comments: false
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }
```